# Why is my network speed to an AFP share slow?

Tags: networking, macosx

I've installed netatalk on my Ubuntu 14.04 box to do timemachine backups to a ZFS pool from my Mac. This is working. However, network speed seems to max out around 11 MiB/s for the transfer over ethernet. Both network cards and my router can handle 100Mbps and both the connection information dialog on the Ubuntu side and Network monitor on the OSX side  report that the connection on en0 (mac) and eth0 (Ubuntu) is 100 Mbps

Speedometer on Ubuntu reports that eth0 is receiving data at around 11.5 MiB/s on average. Can this be speeded up or have I misunderstood the speed I am seeing?

Comment: 100mbps is 12.5MiB/s (8 bits in a byte), so that sounds like you're getting close to full speed...

Comment: I have 16.04 and was connected to my afp share.  I was getting 12-13MB/s.  I installed a recent kernel update and it went to 30-32MB/s.  It’s still well below what appears to be my write speed of my RAID0 drives (250MB/s) on my ODROID XU4 or 110MB/s gigabit xfer.  CPUs 5-8 run at 40-50% during a transfer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As amc commented already - 100 Mbps is 12.5 MB/s or ~11.921 MiB/s, so you're getting close to wire speed. You need to use gigabit NICs and network equipment to get higher speeds.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @KazWolfe it actually answers the question. OP was asking why the connection was "slow" while it was running at 99% of the maximum speed possible using 100 Mbps network cards.